# Can't bind to 'images' since it isn't a known property of 'angular-image-slider' after instaled

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have installed new package using 'npm install angular-image-slider --save'. also i have added sliderModule on app.module.ts file

```
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
    import { SliderModule } from 'angular-image-slider';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
    imports: [

      DragScrollModule,
      SliderModule,
      HttpModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      FileUploadModule,
      TagInputModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      NgxCurrencyModule,
      NgbModule.forRoot(),
      ScrollToModule.forRoot(),
      MetaModule.forRoot(),
      BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'my-app'}),
      DataTablesModule
  ],  
providers: [TravalservicesService, Globalvar, Alwaysguard, Alwaysguradhost, Alwaysguarduserhost, LoaderService, {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateFRParserFormatter}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home.component.html

```
 <div class="row">
    <h2 class="text-uppercase fs-20px text-strong">SENSE</h2>
      <angular-image-slider [images]="imagesUrl"></angular-image-slider>    
  </div>
```

on home.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  viewProviders: [Title],
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
public imagesUrl;

ngOnInit() {
    this.imagesUrl = [
    'IMAGE_URL1.jpg',
    'IMAGE_URL2.jpg',
    'IMAGE_URL3.jpg',
    ];
}
}
```

and it shows some errors
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'images' since it isn't a known property of 'angular-image-slider'.
1. If 'angular-image-slider' is an Angular component and it has 'images' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular-image-slider' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

'angular-image-slider' is not a known element:
1. If 'angular-image-slider' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'angular-image-slider' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Sorry for weird question i'm newbie on angular.

Comment: Can you please tell me In which Module your HomeComponent reside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your component into your declarations section also like this

```
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HomeComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SliderModule
],
```

Because you are not import the component into module so it can't find your library definition code

Comment: CHeck my answer again and try to run project again. Make sure your import order are correct to

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works now. anw, i also edited app-routing.module.ts to `{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},`